# Why does "import module" and then "from package import module" load the module again?

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

I have a package in my PYTHONPATH that looks something like this:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    module.py
        print 'Loading module'
```

If I'm running Python from the `package/` directory (or writing another module in this directory) and type

```
import module
```

it loads module.py and prints out "Loading module" as expected. However, if I then type

```
from package import module
```

it loads module.py and prints "Loading module" *again*, which I don't expect. What's the rationale for this?

Note: I think I understand technically why Python is doing this, because the sys.modules key for `import module` is just `"module"`, but for `from package import module` it's `"package.module"`. So I guess what I want to know is why the key is different here -- why isn't the file's path name used as the key so that Python does what one expects here?

Comment: Think about what using the file name only would mean: It would mean that two packages can't contian a file of the same name because the second import would give the one imported first!

Comment: @delnam, true, though I meant "full path name" -- edited question to clarify.

Comment: Why not just use `module = package.module` if you don't actually want to import it again?

Comment: @Wooble, yes, I know how to solve it in this particular case, it was just an example for my question. What I'd like to know is the rationale for the behaviour I've described.

Comment: Do you mean `import package` or `import package.module`? Because that might make the difference.

Comment: Ned Batchelder has a good PyCon 2016 talk where he talks about a very similar issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAcfPzxB3dk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively, by running code from the `package` directory, you've misconfigured Python.  You shouldn't have put that directory on `sys.path`, since it's inside a package.

Python doesn't use the filename as the key because it's not importing a file, it's importing a module.  Allowing people to do '`import c:\jim\my files\projects\code\stuff`' would encourage all kinds of nastiness.

Consider this case instead: what if you were in `~/foo/package/` and `~/bar` were on `PYTHONPATH` - but ~/bar is just a symlink to `~/foo`?  Do you expect Python to resolve, then deduplicate the symbolic link for you?  What if you put a relative directory on PYTHONPATH, then change directories?  What if 'foo.py' is a symlink to 'bar.py'?  Do you expect both of those to be de-duplicated too?  What if they're not symlinks, but just exact copies?  Adding complex rules to try to do something convenient in ambiguous circumstances means it does something highly inconvenient for other people.  (Python zen 12: in the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.)

Python does something simple here, and it's your responsibility to make sure that the environment is set up correctly.  Now, you could argue that it's not a very good idea to put the current directory on `PYTHONPATH` by default - I might even agree with you - but given that it is there, it should follow the same consistent set of rules that other path entries do.  If it's intended to be run from an arbitrary directory, your application can always remove the current directory from `sys.path` by starting off with `sys.path.remove('')`.

Comment: When we use 'from package import module', then the code (say variable varname) from the init file can be accessed using package.varname?

Comment: No; it would be accessed using `module.varname`.

Comment: But varname is in the pakcage's init file. So how can you access it via modulename?

Answer (score 2):

It is a minor defect of the current module system.

When importing *module*, you do it from the current namespace, which has no name. the values inside this namespace are the same as those in *package*, but the interpreter cannot know it.

When importing *package.module*, you import module from the *package* namespace.

This the reason, that the main.py should be outside the package forlder. 
Many modules have this organisation :

```
package /
    main.py
    package /
        sub_package1/
        sub_package2/
        sub_package3/
        module1.py
        module2.py
```

Calling only main.py make sure the namespaces are correctly set, aka **the current namespace is main.py's**. Its makes impossible to call *import module1.py* in module2.py. You'ld need to call *import package.module1*. Makes things simpler and homogeneous.

And yes, import the current folder as the current nameless folder was a bad idea.
It is a PITA if you go beyond a few scripts. But as Python started there, it was not completely senseless.