# Cyclic module dependencies and relative imports in Python

Tags: python, python-import, circular-dependency

Suppose we have two modules with cyclic dependencies:

```
# a.py
import b
def f(): return b.y
x = 42
```

```
# b.py
import a
def g(): return a.x
y = 43
```

The two modules are in the directory `pkg` with an empty `__init__.py`.  Importing `pkg.a` or `pkg.b` works fine, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/python-circular-or-cyclic-imports/744403#744403).  If I change the imports to relative imports

```
from . import b
```

I get an `ImportError` when trying to import one of the modules:

```
>>> import pkg.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pkg/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import b
  File "pkg/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import a
ImportError: cannot import name a
```

Why do I get this error?  Isn't the situation pretty much the same as above?  (Is this related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282368/why-does-import-module-and-then-from-package-import-module-load-the-module-ag)?)

**Edit**: I'm aware of ways to avoid the circular dependency, but I'm interested in the reason for the error anyway.

Comment: Can you specify the details of the `ImportError` you're receiving when changing to `from . import b`?

Comment: How do you exercise this code? Do you have another module in `pkg` that does something like: `if __name__ == 'main': from . import a`? 

If so, you may want to read [PEP 366](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/), this PEP makes it easier to use relative imports from executable modules with packages.

Comment: if __a__ depends on __b__ and __b__ depends on __a__ why don't you join both in the same file?

Comment: @Pavel: I added the full traceback of the error message.  In the actual library, `__init__.py` imports names from `a` and `b`, and programs using the package import the package.

Comment: @JBernardo:  The file would get very big, and the functionality is actually quite well spearated.  `b` implements a later processing step in some data pipeline and operates on types in `a`.  In `a`, I add a few convenience methods to the classes that forward the call to functions in `b`.  Apart from this, I'd like to have an explanation for the above behaviour.

Comment: Or put those convenience methods in a third module which depends on both a and b.

Comment: @JBernardo: The design is actually quite clean and not broken at all.  There are solutions that would break the cycle, but all of them are less nice than the current solution.  But as stated before -- I ask this question because I'm interested in the answer.

Comment: @John: They are methods on classes defined in `a`.  I don't want to monkey-patch them in later.  Derived classes wouldn't do since the functions in `a` return classes from `a`, and these classes should have the methods.  If I'd return classes from `c`, I'd have a cyclic dependency again.  Anyway, all this is somehow missing the point.  I'd be really interested in an explanation of the error.

Comment: @Sven I can't answer why your code is not working, but as we're talking about it, Circular dependencies are __known software anti-patterns and should be avoided__.

Comment: @JBernardo: Well, I'm aware fo this and carefully thought about it before I introduced the cycle.  I decided that the interface improvement by the convenience methods outweighs breaking some abstract principle in this case.  Note that the circular dependency wouldn't disappear if I join the files -- it would just be a circular dependency inside a single file.

Comment: @Sven: I've played with various ways of writing the import statements on my 2.6 Python. I exercised the imports using `python -c "import pkg.a"`. I can report that `from pkg import ...` and `from . import ...` forms do not work, but `import a` and `import b` do. It would seem import cycles are only allowed in the latter case. Why, I do not know. Up-voting the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Circular (or cyclic) imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/python-circular-or-cyclic-imports)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First let's start with how `from import` work in python:

Well first let's look at the byte code:

```
>>> def foo():
...     from foo import bar

>>> dis.dis(foo)
2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (('bar',))
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (foo)
              9 IMPORT_FROM              1 (bar)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (bar)
             15 POP_TOP             
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

hmm  interesting :), so `from foo import bar` is translated to first `IMPORT_NAME foo` which equivalent to `import foo` and then `IMPORT_FROM bar`.

*Now what [`IMPORT_FROM`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#opcode-IMPORT_FROM) do ?*

let's see what python do when he found [`IMPORT_FROM`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/ceval.c#l2345):

```
TARGET(IMPORT_FROM)
     w = GETITEM(names, oparg);
     v = TOP();
     READ_TIMESTAMP(intr0);
     x = import_from(v, w);
     READ_TIMESTAMP(intr1);
     PUSH(x);
     if (x != NULL) DISPATCH();
     break;
```

Well basically he get the the names to import from, which is in our `foo()` function will be `bar`, then he pop from the frame stack the value `v` which is the return of the the last opcode executed which is `IMPORT_NAME`, then call the function `import_from()` with this two arguments :

```
static PyObject *
import_from(PyObject *v, PyObject *name)
{
    PyObject *x;

    x = PyObject_GetAttr(v, name);

    if (x == NULL && PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_AttributeError)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_ImportError, "cannot import name %S", name);
    }
    return x;
}
```

As you can see the `import_from()` function is quiet easy, it try first to get the attribute `name` from the module `v`, if it don't exist it raise `ImportError` else return this attribute.

*Now what this have to do with relative import ?*

Well relative import like `from . import b` are equivalent for example in the case that is in the OP question to `from pkg import b`.

But how this happen ? To understand this we should take a look to the [`import.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/10ecf8576eb2/Python/import.c) module of python specially to the function [get_parent()](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/10ecf8576eb2/Python/import.c#l2854). As you see the function is quiet long to list here but in general what it does when it see a relative import is to try to replace the dot `.` with the parent package depending on the `__main__` module, which is again from the OP question is the package `pkg`.

Now let's put all this together and try to figure out why we end up with the behavior in the OP question.

For this it will help us if we can see what python do when doing imports, well it's our lucky day python come already with this feature which can be enabled by running it in extra verbose mode `-vv`.

So using the command line: `python -vv -c 'import pkg.b'`:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import pkg # directory pkg
# trying pkg/__init__.so
# trying pkg/__init__module.so
# trying pkg/__init__.py
# pkg/__init__.pyc matches pkg/__init__.py
import pkg # precompiled from pkg/__init__.pyc
# trying pkg/b.so
# trying pkg/bmodule.so
# trying pkg/b.py
# pkg/b.pyc matches pkg/b.py
import pkg.b # precompiled from pkg/b.pyc
# trying pkg/a.so
# trying pkg/amodule.so
# trying pkg/a.py
# pkg/a.pyc matches pkg/a.py
import pkg.a # precompiled from pkg/a.pyc
#   clear[2] __name__
#   clear[2] __file__
#   clear[2] __package__
#   clear[2] __name__
#   clear[2] __file__
#   clear[2] __package__
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pkg/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import a
  File "pkg/a.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import a
ImportError: cannot import name a
# clear __builtin__._
```

*hmm what just happen before the `ImportError` ?*

**First)** `from . import a`  in `pkg/b.py` is called, which is translated as explained above to `from pkg import a`, which is again in bytecode is equivalent to `import pkg; getattr(pkg, 'a')`. But wait a minute `a` is a module too ?! 
Well here came the fun part if we have something like `from module|package import module` in this case a second import will happen which is the import of the module in the import clause. So again in the OP example we need now to import `pkg/a.py`, and as you know first of all we set in our `sys.modules` a key for our new module which will be `pkg.a` and then we continue our interpretation of the module `pkg/a.py`, but before the module `pkg/a.py` finish importing it call `from . import b`.

Now come the **Second)** part, `pkg/b.py` will be imported and in it turn it will first attempt to `import pkg` which because `pkg` is already imported so there is a key `pkg` in our `sys.modules` it will just return the value of that key. Then it will `import b` set the `pkg.b` key in `sys.modules` and start the interpretation. And we arrive to this line `from . import a` !

**But** remember `pkg/a.py` is already imported which mean `('pkg.a' in sys.modules) == True` so the import will be skipped, and only the `getattr(pkg, 'a')` will be called , but what will happen ? python didn't finish importing `pkg/a.py` !? So only `getattr(pkg, 'a')` will be called , and this will raise an `AttributeError` in the `import_from()` function, which will be translated to `ImportError(cannot import name a)`.

**DISCLAIM** : This is my own effort to understand what is happening inside the interpreter, i'm far away of being an expert.

**EDIt:** This answer was rephrased because when i tried to read it again i remarked how my answer was bad formulated, hope now it will be more useful :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and for actually looking at the sources.  I'm still not really satisfied.  Two things confuse me: 1. In your point (1), `from pkg import b` is executed.  Why does this work even when `b` obviously isn't in the namespace of `pkg` yet?  Isn't this the same situation as in the next step, `from pkg import a`? 2. Cyclic dependencies of modules usually work because the empty module object is inserted into `sys.modules` before the module body is executed.  Why isn't the empty module object `a` inserted in `pkg` before the module body is executed?

Comment: @seven: 1. because `pkg.b` is not is `sys.modules` so we need to import it first set the entry `pkg.b` in `sys.modules` then after the import succeed add `b` to the namespace of pkg.  2. the `a` module is inserted at the end of the import in the package namespace because if the import of `a` fail (you can raise an exception in your module and see) we don't want it to hang out in the namespace of `pkg`. Basically the adding of the module imported to the namespace of the package is done after the success of the import.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you put into this answer.  Now it makes it really clear what is happening.

Comment: @Sven: it's was my pleasure and a very good challenge indeed :)

Answer (score 4):

(Incedentally, the relative import doesn't matter.  Using `from pkg import`... reveals the same exception.)

I think what's going on here is that the difference between `from foo import bar` and `import foo.bar` is that in the first one, the value `bar` could be module in pkg `foo` or it could be a variable in a module `foo`.  In the second case, it's invalid for `bar` to be anything but a module/package.

This would matter because if bar is known to be a module, then the contents of `sys.modules` is sufficient to populate it.  If it might be a variable in the `foo` module, then the interpreter must actually look into the contents of `foo`, but while importing `foo`, that would be invalid; the actual module has not been populated yet.

In the case of a relative import, we understand `from . import bar` to mean import the bar module from the package that contains the current module, but this is really just syntactic sugar, the `.` name is translated to a fully qualified name and passed to `__import__()`, and thus it looks for all the world like the ambigious `from foo import bar`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, I don't think this explains it.  If it was invalid to look at the contents of `foo` while it is being imported, also non-cyclic imports should fail: If `foo.bar` does `from foo import quux`, and I import `foo.bar`, the interpreter also has to look at the contents of `foo` while it is being imported, and this works fine.  Am I making sense?

Answer (score 1):

As an additional Note:

I had the following module Structure:

```
base
 +guiStuff
   -gui
 +databaseStuff
   -db
 -basescript
```

I wanted to be able to run my script by `import base.basescript`, however this failed with an error since the `gui` file had an `import base.databaseStuff.db` which caused an import of `base`. Since `base` was only registered as `__main__` it caused a second execution of the whole imports and the error above unless I used an external script above `base` thus importing `base` / `basescript` only once. To prevent this I put the following in my base script:

```
if  __name__ == '__main__' or \
  not '__main__' in sys.modules or \
  sys.modules['__main__'].__file__ != __file__: 
    #imports here
```