# What is the best way to deal with import cycle in Python?

Tags: python, python-import

In our projects we have level 'controls' with the following modules: 'grid', 'gridcell', 'combo' and etc. Grid module imports gridcell module since grid consists of cells, while any cell can contain combo inside it. So initially we starting to use 'from ... import ...' statements inside these classes the following way:

```
#grid.py
from controls.gridcell import cell
#gridcell.py
from controls.combo import combo
```

But this was ok until we start using grid as a combo content. As soon as we start doing this  we were required to add 'from grid import grid' statement into the 'combo.py'. After doing this we get an import exception:

```
from controls.gridcell import gridcell 
ImportError: Cannot import name gridcell
```

EDITED:

I have tried also 'import ... as ...' and get the following error:

```
import controls.gridcell as gridcell
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gridcell'
```

I have read several articles and all that i have found about how to solve this is to use 'import' statement without from, e.g:

```
#grid.py
import controls.gridcell
#gridcell.py
import controls.combo
#combo.py
import controls.grid
```

But this leads us to use full names like 'controls.gridcell.cell', 'controls.combo.combo', 'controls.grid.grid' and so on.

So my question is - Is there any other way how to do this(so it would be available to use shorter names) or this is the only way of how to resolve this issue?

Sorry if i miss something

Thanx to all

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351805/cyclic-module-dependencies-and-relative-imports-in-python

Comment: @Sven, yes you are right, missed it, sorry for notifying me.

Answer (score 9):

```
import controls.gridcell as gridcell
```

etc. etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Better yet, for this particular case: `from controls import gridcell`. 'import as' is mostly useful when you want a *different* name for the local name.

Comment: @Thomas: I think the OP ran into the problem described in [this question I asked a few days back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351805/cyclic-module-dependencies-and-relative-imports-in-python).  When you have cyclic module depedencies, only `import ...` works, while `from ... import ...` doesn't.

Comment: Wow it works, thank you, I have tried this previously but due to unknown reason for me it was not working in my previous console, but it works well on 2.7. Is there any way of how to do the same using the following syntax 'gridcell = __import__('controls.gridcell'))' or it not acceptable?

Comment: Modules within packages are not created in the same manner as global names, so I don't believe that `from ... import ...` will be a problem. I just really like `as`.

Comment: @Atrsiom: `__import__()` returns the top-level package; you will have to access the `gridcell` attribute to get the module.

Comment: Indeed, `from controls import gridcell` and `import controls.gridcell as gridcell` both work (and fail) in the same situations (and are almost identical in how they're implemented.)

Comment: @Ignacio, oh, yes - your truth, thank you, just has rechecked it.

Comment: I have tried both ways on my real project and both of them throwing exceptions. I edited my question to provide more details on this.

Answer (score 4):

you can also move the imports into the functions.

```
def foo():
    from controls.gridcell import cell
    from controls.combo import combo
```

if you have an `init()` function this can be convenient.