# Cyclic import between sub-package and contained module

Tags: python, import, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cyclic module dependencies and relative imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351805/cyclic-module-dependencies-and-relative-imports-in-python)

I am trying to understand how sub-packages and relative imports work in Python. I am using Python 3.2.

The following example consists of a package (`package`) and a module (`package/module.py`) within that package, where that module and the package's init module (`package/__init__.py`) use members from each other (only the `import` statements are shown). `test.py` is launched with the directory containing `package` in its `sys.path`.

```
package/__init__.py:
    from . import module
```

```
package/module.py:
    import package
```

```
test.py:
    import package
```

This works fine. But when I move `package` into another package (`lib`), it breaks:

```
lib/__init__.py:
    # empty
```

```
lib/package/__init__.py:
    from . import module
```

```
package/module.py:
    from .. import package
```

```
test.py:
    from lib import package
```

Running `test.py` will fail with the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib import package
  File "/Users/ims/test/lib/package/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import module
  File "/Users/ims/test/lib/package/module.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .. import package
ImportError: cannot import name package
```

My questions are:

- What is the reason for the cyclic import to work inside a top-level package but not inside a sub-package?
- Is there a work-around for this problem?

Comment: Why are you using 3.3?  It's pre-alpha!

Comment: "Is there a work-around for this problem?".  Yes.  Search.  This question is asked frequently.  Search for "Python Cyclic Import".

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: Oops, that's a typo. I'm using version 3.2.2.