# Python cyclic imports fail when using from package import module syntax

Tags: python, import, cyclic-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cyclic module dependencies and relative imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351805/cyclic-module-dependencies-and-relative-imports-in-python)

Consider the following example of cyclic imports in python:

main.py:

```
from pkg import foo
```

pkg/__init.py__:

```
# empty
```

pkg/foo.py:

```
from pkg import bar
```

pkg/bar.py:

```
from pkg import foo
```

Running main.py will cause an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg import foo
  File "/path/to/pkg/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg import bar
  File "/path/to/pkg/bar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg import foo
ImportError: cannot import name foo
```

Changing bar.py to:

```
# from pkg import foo
import pkg.foo
```

will make the example work.

Why does this happen? Shouldn't *import package.module" and "from package import module" be equivalent (except for the extra name binding in the latter)?

Comment: I've tested with python 2.7.3.

Comment: Python 3.2.3 behaves in the same way.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/python-circular-or-cyclic-imports) might help you. In particular the second answer.
Or even better [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6378337/510937) answer.

Comment: Thanks @Bakariu. The links give exactly the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to understand that:

- The `sys.modules` variable play the role of a cache in the import mechanize which mean that if we import a module the first time, an entry containing the name of this module is added to `sys.modules`, so that when we try to import this same module next time, we will only get the already cached module from `sys.modules` and we will not execute the module again.
- The difference between `import pkg.foo` and `from pkg import foo` is that the second is equivalent too: `import pkg.foo` followed by `getattr(pkg, 'foo')`. (check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351805/c) for more detail)

Now what happen in your first example is the following:

1- In `main.py`: we start by executing the line `from pkg import foo`, so first the entry `pkg.foo` is added to `sys.modules` (i.e. `'pkg.foo' in sys.modules == True`) than we **try** to import `foo`.

2- In `foo.py`: While importing `foo` we end up executing this line: `from pkg import bar` and again the entry `pkg.bar` is added to `sys.modules`; and than we start importing `bar`, what is important to note here is that we are still executing `foo.py`, so we are kind off still executing this line `from pkg import foo` from `main.py`.

3- In `bar.py`: while now importing `bar.py` we end up executing the line: `from pkg import foo`, but  remember we have already an entry in `sys.modules` for `pkg.foo` which mean that executing `foo.py` will be skipped and the import mechanize will get us instead the `sys.modules['pkg.foo']` entry, and now we will excute `getattr(pkg, 'foo')` as explained above, but remember 'pkg.foo' didn't finish importing; which mean that there is no attribute `foo` which explain the error.

Now if you put in `bar.py` only `import pkg.foo` this will not have the line that cause us the problem last time which is: `getattr(pkg, 'foo')`.

HTH,

Comment: I'd already linked your answer in a comment and flagged this question as a duplicate, since the problem is actually the same.

Comment: Thanks @mouad. I couldn't have asked for a better answer. I reason (if I'm not mistaken) that `getattr(pkg, 'foo')` is used instead of `sys.modules['pkg.foo']` because the same `from x import y` syntax must work when `x` is a module and `y` a field in module `x`.