# Best way to do parent child relationship in Python 3 with circular dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, circular-dependency

In python 3, I have a RouterDevice class, and an Interface class that are in different files.  The RouterDevice has a list of interfaces, and an interface has a reference to its parent RouterDevice.

I understand an issue, which is what I am having, with circular dependencies as described in this [stackoverflow.com question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351805/cyclic-module-dependencies-and-relative-imports-in-python?lq=1)

My question is, how do I actually fix this in a sensible way?  I could do my import inside of the `__init__` in my Interface class, but I need it before, as I take a RoutingDevice as one of `__init__` parameters.

```
class NetworkInterface:
    def __init__(self, parentDevice: RoutingDevice):
```

I know that having circular dependencies is generally considered bad practice, but having a parent/child realtionship seems to be one that some feel to be an exception, so I would like to figure out how to make it work in its current structure, if at all possible of course.

Comment: When you say "The RouterDevice has a list of interfaces", do you mean it subclasses those interfaces?

Comment: @Addison I mean that inside of the class RouterDevice, there is a line self.__interfaces = [], which will later get appended with instances of the Interface class as they are created from a parsed config file.  Does this help?

Comment: So that sounds like if you separate out the parsing logic from RouterDevice, then RouterDevice itself doesn't have to depend on the interfaces.  Only the code that does the config file parsing will have to depend on the interfaces.  Then the code that uses RouterDevice can be responsible for using the config file parser to populate the RouterDevice's list of interfaces.

Comment: @Addison They are more tightly coupled than that though.  For example, the router needs to go through its list of interfaces to look for something, like if an ip is in the interfaces subnet.  The Interface needs to have a reference to the parent router because some things I do populate a list of interfaces from multiple routers.  When I find an interface of interest in that list, I need to know what router it belongs too.  The parsing is already done in the interface constructor when given a chunk of text that belongs to that single interface

Comment: @jacobcase94: It's okay if code within methods needs to use the other class, as long as each module's top-level code (including the class definitions themselves) doesn't reference the other's.  In your example, the only problem is the type annotation.  Do you really need that (i.e., do you have code that makes use of it)?  If all you do is call methods on `self.parentDevice` from within methods, it should be much easier to resolve the circular dependency.