# How to import classes/functions from submodules into one another?

Tags: python, python-module

Suppose I have a python module set out as follows:

```
setup.py
tpkg/
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
```

where `__init__.py` is:

```
from .module1 import class1
from .module2 import class2
```

`module1.py` is:

```
from .module2 import class2

class class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._who = "Class 1"

    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm {}".format(self._who)

    def otherclass(self):
        print(str(class2()))
```

`module2.py` is:

```
from .module1 import class1

class class2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._who = "Class 2"

    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm {}".format(self._who)

    def otherclass(self):
        print(str(class1()))
```

and `setup.py` is:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="tpkg",
      version="0.0.1",
      packages=["tpkg"])
```

So, here both the modules need to import the class that is contained in the other module.

If I install this module and try to `import tpkg` I get the error

```
In [1]: import tpkg
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-834a70240c6c> in <module>()
----> 1 import tpkg

build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tpkg/__init__.py in <module>()

build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tpkg/module1.py in <module>()

build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tpkg/module2.py in <module>()

ImportError: cannot import name class1
```

So, my question is, how should I actually go about importing the classes from the two modules into each other?

**Update** This question is slightly different to that given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351805/cyclic-module-dependencies-and-relative-imports-in-python), which asks why there is a problem with cyclic imports, rather than the question of how to solve the problem of cyclic imports, which is what I needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cyclic module dependencies and relative imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351805/cyclic-module-dependencies-and-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: @Ivan. That question only asks **why** the import error happens. This question is asking how to avoid the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normally try to avoid circular dependencies:

http://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/

Otherwise you can try local imports

```
class class1(object):
def __init__(self):
    self._who = "Class 1"

def __str__(self):
    return "I'm {}".format(self._who)

def otherclass(self):
    from test2 import class2

    print(str(class2()))

test = class1()

test.otherclass()
```

and

```
class class2(object):
def __init__(self):
    self._who = "Class 2"

def __str__(self):
    return "I'm {}".format(self._who)

def otherclass(self):
    from test1 import class1
    print(str(class1()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving from relative path import to absolute and from `from ... import...` syntaxe to `import ...` (in modules files) should fix your problem

`__init__.py`

```
from tpkg.module2 import class2
from tpkg.module1 import class1
```

`module1.py`

```
import tpkg.module2

class class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._who = "Class 1"

    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm {}".format(self._who)

    def otherclass(self):
    print(str(tpkg.module2.class2))
```

`module2.py`

```
import tpkg.module1

class class2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._who = "Class 2"

    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm {}".format(self._who)

    def otherclass(self):
        print(str(tpkg.module1.class1))
```

Test:

```
>>> import tpkg
>>> c = tpkg.module1.Class1()
>>> c
< tpkg.module1.Class1 object at 0x10535ffd0>
>>> c.otherclass()
<class 'tpkg.module2.Class2'>
>>>
```

Comment: Indeed my previous answer was stupid and fixed nothing. But I think my new answer can fix your issue without having to use local import.